# Why is it forbidden to check-raise in some Casino?

Tags: betting-strategy, rules

I've heard that check-raising isn't allowed everywhere. What is the reason behind that?

Comment: Do you have any examples of this? As far as I know there is no reason why you wouldnt be allowed to Check Raise.

Comment: I can't tell you the exact places where it's not allowed to check-raise. It's mentionned there http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Check-raise but no reasons are given.

Comment: Interesting. I have never heard that before. I dont see why it wouldnt be allowed.

Comment: I've played in home games where there's a house rule for no check-raising.  It was to try and 'level the playing field' between the experienced and the inexperienced.  Never seen it in the wild though.

Comment: It's actually more weird than interesting. If I ever sit down at a table and hear something like this, I would just get up and walk away. This rule would be just too stupid to be acceptable. The one from WSOP which says that you can't talk about your hand during the hand (I hope I remember it correctly :D ) also comes pretty close...

Comment: @SoboLAN I think not talking about the hand that you are involved in is reasonable (for a few reasons, maybe etiquette more than anything) but I don't think it is enforced that much or it certainly didn't used to be just look at Jamie Gold. I am totally with you on the no check raising thing- that's just wierd!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The point is to make players feel like they're not getting hustled by a shark. Some people, particularly newer players, think it's an unfriendly thing to do. The game will tend to have a little more action than one where check-raise is allowed, which means that the rake will be a bit larger.

In practice, however, it actually favors more experienced players. The Excalibur ran a 1-3 spread limit hold'em "Beginners" game in the mid-90s, with the only difference from the regular 1-4-8 hold'em game (other than the limit) being that check-raise wasn't allowed.

When I noticed this game, it was the only place I played for months, until it wasn't really going anymore. My adjustments were very simple - I played much tighter in early position and would play almost any two cards on the button if there were enough players seeing the flop. Regardless of what I thought of the flop, I'd almost always bet if it was checked to me. I don't have detailed records for the game, but I recall almost always winning. I was certainly disappointed when I stopped in one night and found out they weren't spreading it anymore.

So, the real reason it isn't used in card rooms much is because it increases the rate at which the losers run out of money.

Comment: It also used to be considered rude. In old school Nevada casinos (not LV, where professionals played), it was considered improper etiquette to not "bet your hand." It was akin to 'slow-rolling' or any other poker faux pas.

Answer (score 2):

It is unlikely that any comercial card room would ban check-raising in standard limit or no-limit games such as Stud, Hold'em or Omaha. The rules for some lowball limit games prohibit or restrict check-raising.

Roberts Rules of Poker goes into more detail as to what games (Ex:A-5 Lowball) and on what streets check-raising is prohibited.

It might be common in some home games to limit weaker players losses and to keep it *"friendly"*. And of course there may be some card room somewhere that does but I could find no evidence of that.

Comment: I don't believe any card rooms ban check raising any more. When hold'em first came to California in 1987 I am aware of one card room that did not allow check raising. Perhaps there were more.